# How to implement and use vectors in C++/CLI Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2019, c++-cli

I've been trying to figure out how to implement vectors in the .Net framework with C++ but I keep getting errors that's saying its not able to define the vector. I'm also getting squiggly lines saying "namespace cliext has no member vector".

```
  #include <cliext>

  String^ toBinary(int decimal) {

    cliext::vector<String^>^ binary;

    String^ finalBinary;

    while (decimal != 1) {

        if (decimal % 2 == 1)
            binary.push_back("1");
        else {
            binary.push_back("0");

        }

        decimal /= 2;

        floor(decimal);

    }

    if (decimal == 1) binary.push_back("1");

    for (int i = 0; i < binary->Capacity; i++)
        finalBinary += binary[i];


    return finalBinary;

}
```

Comment: Start from the top of the error list, it tells you that the #include failed first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/vector-stl-clr?view=msvc-160), you need to

```
#include <cliext/vector>
```